# Directive formatting does not keep up with fast input

Tags: angular, input, formatting, directive, angular-directive

I am trying to format an input field by transforming the letters by the user to valid initials: Uppercase, separated by a dot.

Input has to formatted as the user types and not afterwards.

**new-customer-form.component.html**

```html
<input formatInitials>
```

**format-initials.directive.ts**

```c
import { Directive, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '[formatInitials]'
})
export class FormatInitialsDirective {
    @HostListener('keyup', [ '$event' ]) private format(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        const {target} = event;
        const {value} = target;

        const isAlphabeticKeyCode = event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90;

        if (isAlphabeticKeyCode) { // Only separate with a dot for alphabetic chars 
            target.value = `${value.toUpperCase()}.`;
        }
    }

}
```

When I type slow the formatting works fine, but when I type faster the formatting gets messed up so instead of `P.J.S` I get `PJ.S..`.

It looks like the input is being processed before the directive ran.
How can I make sure the input is only processed once the formatting has happened?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the previous answer, `keyup` cannot be used as you don't necessary leave a key before pressing the next key while typing fast.

You need to use `keydown` instead along with `preventDefault()` to manipulate the input entered before placing it in the input.

Try this in your directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[formatInitials]'
})
export class FormatInitialsDirective {
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) 
  private format(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const { target } = event;
    const { value } = target;

    const isAlphabeticKeyCode = event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90;

    if (isAlphabeticKeyCode) {
      event.preventDefault();
      target.value += `${event.key.toUpperCase()}.`;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-dot-separator)

Answer (score 1):

With the above ansfer from @nash11 I got it to work, but was having trouble retaining the value in my form, so I've added the part about updating the value of the `formControl` here:

```java
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: 'input[formatInitials]',
})
export class FormatInitialsDirective {
    @Input() public formControl: FormControl;

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    public format(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        const { target } = event;
        const isAlphabeticKeyCode = event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90;

        if (isAlphabeticKeyCode) {
            event.preventDefault();
            (<HTMLInputElement>target).value += `${event.key.toUpperCase()}.`;
            this.formControl.setValue((<HTMLInputElement>target).value);
        }
    }
}
```